# How to deal with navigating after a dispatch in react

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having trouble with `react-navigation` in that I can not find a way to go to navigate to a screen after the data has been placed into the `redux` store. I tried to do many things but to no avail, the problem keeps persisting. The problem is that the `redux` store will not have dispatched fast enough before the screen pops up and the screen then errors because certain parts of the json file do not exist. I am wondering if there is a certain to halt the navigation until after the store is updated with the necessary JSON file.

This is the portion of my app where the problem occurs.

```
_onPress = () => {
    if (this.state.taxonA == "" || this.state.taxonB == "") {
      Alert.alert("One or more fields have been left empty.");
      return;
    }
    let url = V.sprintf(
      "http://timetree.igem.temple.edu/api/pairwise/%s/%s",
      this.state.taxonA,
      this.state.taxonB
    );
    const { fetchData } = this.props;
    fetchData(url);
    console.log("should have fetched");
    //while(this.props.response.isFetching == true){}
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Picker");
  };
```

this is the `fetchData` function

```
export const fetchData = url => {
  console.log("Should enter async dispatch");
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchingRequest());
    try{
      let response = await fetch(url);
      let json = await response.json();
      let dispatchChecker = dispatch(fetchingSuccess(json));
      console.log("DISPATCH", dispatchChecker);
      console.log("JSON",json);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
    }catch(error){
      console.log("ERROR",error);
      dispatch(fetchingFailure(error));
    }
  };
};
```

The output should be a transition from one screen to another screen. but instead the app will get a red screen with the statement `cannot read property of 'found_taxon_a' of null` where found_taxon_a is a object in the JSON file that is fetched.

Comment: where does dispatch in fetchData come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait for `fetchData` to complete before navigating to a different screen:

```js
fetchData(url)
  .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Picker'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Do something'));
```